rust `&mut buffer[..]` vs just `&mut buffer`
In the Rust documentation for std::io::Read::read() I came across this example:
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut buffer = [0; 10];

    // read up to 10 bytes
    let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..])?;
    // Is there any difference between the previous line and the next one?
    // let n = f.read(&mut buffer)?;

    println!("The bytes: {:?}", &buffer[..n]);
    Ok(())
}

You can see let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..])?;, buffer[ .. ] contains all values from start to end and then we have a mutable reference to them.
Would it make any difference if I would write let n = f.read(&mut buffer)?; instead?
I tried it and to me it seems the same, but I wondered why authors used &mut buffer[..], am I missing something?

&mut buffer only means the same thing as &mut buffer[..] in places where deref coercion is allowed, assuming buffer is a Vec

It's an array in the example, so technically not deref, but it is a coercion.

To coerce &mut [u8; 10] to &mut [u8]

@TimsibAdnap I would recommend .as_mut_slice() over &mut [..], though. But I agree with OP, a simple &mut would work too and is better imo.

@drewtato If you wanna be pedantic, it is an unsize coercion.

The types are different:









buffer
[u8; 10]


&mut buffer
&mut [u8; 10]


&mut buffer[..]
&mut [u8]


buffer.as_mut_slice()
&mut [u8]



So why can a function that wants a &mut [u8] argument take a &mut buffer?
The magic here is in automatic type coercion, which states that a &mut [u8; 10] can be coerced into a &mut [u8] automatically.
Functionally, there is no difference. It's like the difference between an explicit and implicit cast. &mut [..] converts to a slice explicitly and no coercion happens, &mut does not convert explicitly and an implicit coercion happens. The resulting machine code will be identical.
For more information about the difference between [u8; 10] and [u8], read What is the difference between a slice and an array?.
So writing f.read(&mut buffer) is perfectly fine and, in my opinion, preferred to f.read(&mut buffer[..]). It's just easier to read.
EDIT: @ChayimFriedman pointed out that coercion does not always happen automatically, which is correct. Coercion can only happen at coercion sites. The relevant coercion site for this example is using a variable as the 'argument for a function call'. If you have a situation where no coercion site is present, then the explicit conversion might indeed be required.

Note that sometimes (not in this case) coercion won't kick in, so explicitness will be necessary,
